# iOS 9 NSUserActivity for search does not update it's thumbnail

Tags: ios, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I use `NSUSerActivity` and `CoreSpotlight` for indexing. I set the `thumbnailURL` in the `contentAttributesSet` property as usual. Images are downloaded from a server and the activity object is created before the image get's downloaded. So I set a "placeholder" image and when I have the chance I update `contentAttributesSet.thumbnailURL` to the correct one. But when I try to search for the same item in Spotlight the image stays the same.

Is there any special condition that I have to be aware of when updating such info?

Comment: What are you setting the `thumbnailURL` to? Have you tried using the `thumbnailData` property instead?

Comment: I am setting it to a file URL located in the Caches directory. It is way easier than using the data property because of the needed resizing of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnail URL is only for `local` urls. not remote ones. You have to use thumbnailData.

Comment: It is used for a local file. It turns out there is a bug with that. There are people complaining about the same issue on the Apple forums as well. No matter how you set it, once a thumbnail is set there is no replacing it.

Comment: I didn't try `thumbnailURL` but the problem of `thumbnailData` - `CoreSpotlight` caches it and it seems you can't refresh this cache via code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that was a bug in iOS 9.0 - 9.2. It seems to be working well on iOS 9.3+

Comment: i have the same issue for 9.3.3

Comment: Hmm that is strange. I am sure they fixed it with 9.3. I will double check and post if it reintroduced in my app.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can determine, this is an issue with caching a thumbnail for a specific `NSUserActivity`. The `CoreSpotlight` framework seems to associate the icon data with the `activityType`, so even creating a new `NSUserActivity` object won't allow you to update the icon image. The best you can do is to keep track of all the persistent identifiers internally, delete the old one, and create a brand new NSUserActivity which the user will have to treat as a new shortcut as well.

It's definitely a dumb issue, and I'd have hoped that in the 3.5 years since iOS 9 came out, Apple would have introduced a way to update an `NSUserActivity`'s thumbnail image.